# PHP move_uploaded_file is Not uploading Images when full web path is given in Unix system

Tags: php, html, unix

My Following code is working fine when I set

> $target = "size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";

But **Not Working** in **Actual php Code** when full web address path is given though 777 Unix access is granted to system.

> **I am trying upload an image from SubDomain to Main Domain, So i need to give Full Path.**

**Page**: http://**subdomain**.examples.com/

**Code:**

```
$target = "http://examples.com/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_image"]["tmp_name"],$target);
```

For your reference, following are values of above code line...

```
echo $_FILES["item_image"]["tmp_name"]; --> "/tmp/php6RNC28"

echo $target --> "http://examples.com/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg"
```

Even tried with relative path instead of http, No luck : **/home/direc/www/size_images**

No use of placing error code. its not returning any error.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: you cannot do that, PHP cannot use a URL as the target of this function.

Comment: Is there any way to upload the file from sub domain to main domain ?

Comment: Are subdomain and maindomain hosted on the same machine?

Comment: You can send a file via POST with cURL in PHP

Comment: Can't you just have the upload script on **Main Domain** and then use a relative/local path?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid : I should have the script in sub domain only

Comment: Since you say they're on the same box, just provide the /path/to/maindomain/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg in $target

Comment: @DigitalChris : tried with it but no luck.. subdomain : home/direc/subdomain/ Main domain: is /home/direc/www/size_images/

Comment: What do you mean no luck? What error did you get? You have to have write rights to the directory, so verify that, and you could also try a relative directory call like `../../size_images/[file]`

Comment: @DigitalChris: there is no error., I said error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); is also not helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, You need to use only **relative path** instead of domain path. Domain path doesn't work

```
$target = "size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_image"]["tmp_name"],$target);
```

instead of ,

```
$target = "http://examples.com/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_image"]["tmp_name"],$target);
```

**Send a file via POST with cURL and PHP** Ref:  http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: I said working fine when I set * $target = "size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";

Comment: this is the correct answer imo.  if it's working fine then why are you changing it to do something wrong?   Are you expecting PHP is going to upload the file to some remote server, or somehow resolve apache's config to know where that file should go on your local server?  it don't make no sense.

Comment: @JoeT : I need to load the file from subdomain to main domain. So if I use /Size_images ... it will be uploaded into subdomain itself..

Comment: @logan can you try this url, using curl to upload domain to domain -  http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: then you just need the server path to the main domain folder as your target

Comment: @JoeT : Yes., tried with it but no luck..
subdomain : home/direc/subdomain/ 
Main domain: is /home/direc/www/size_images/

Comment: you could try the target relative to your current path; $target = "../../www/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/size_images/14_20131216231522_cashew.jpg";
```

If you want to upload from  **subdomain.mydomain.com** to **mydomain.com** simply put the upload script on **mydomain.com** and then use a relative path.

Comment: I have tried using relative path but no use..
Now, $target --> /home/direc/www/size_images/

Comment: @logan, in your document root, do you have separate directories for each domain [subdomain] and [main_domain]?

Comment: yes, Subdomain is /home/direc/subdomain/
Main domain is /home/direc/www/size_images/

Comment: I need to use my code sub domain only! whatever admin uploads in subdomain page should reflect in main domain page for end users

Comment: @logan Surely the **www** directory is your root directory. Why is the sub-domain directory outside of root? Are you sure you didn't miss a **www** in `/home/direc/subdomain/`?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how [move-uploaded-file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) works. It is similar to "File Save", namely you have to tell the PHP script a locally-writeable directory and file name where the file goes.

You mention you're trying to go from "subdomain" to "main domain"... if these two web urls are hosted on the same machine, this will be possible, you will just choose the directory that has the files for the "main domain" site.

Comment: It is present in same host only ! home/direc/subdomain/ Main domain is /home/direc/www/size_images/

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a relative path.. absolute path would not work.

Also make sure that you know the difference between "/" and "./" But I would strongly recommend to either use configuration variables(in case of framework) OR constants to store file path.

Former point to root and later point to current directory..

Comment: can you give me some sample

Comment: Suppose current directory is "/home/user/project/css/". Now "./" refers to the current directory where you are currently which is "CSS" and if you want to access something from same directory, you can use "./filename". On the other hand,if you want to access something from "home" then you should write "/filename". Hope that helps!